# One single Azure SQL query is consuming almost all query_stats.total_worker_time and query_stats.execution_count

Tags: entity-framework-4, azure-sql-database, query-performance, sql-execution-plan

I'm running a production website for 4 years with azure SQL.
With help of 'Top Slow Request' query from alexsorokoletov on github I have 1 super slow query according to Azure query stats.

The one on top is the one that uses a lot of CPU.

[image: Slowest Query]

When looking at the linq query and the execution plans / live stats, I can't find the bottleneck yet.

[image: estimated plan]

And the live stats

[image: stats]

[image: reads and writes]

The join from results to project is not directly, there is a projectsession table in between, not visible in the query, but maybe under the hood of entity framework.

Might I be affected by parameter sniffing? Can I reset a hash?  Maybe the optimized query plan was used in 2014 and now result table is about 4Million rows and the query is far from optimal?

If I run this query in Management Studio its very fast!
Is it just the stats that are wrong?

Regards

Vincent - The Netherlands.

Comment: You mention parameter sniffing but the queries in your question have hard-coded literal values. I suggest you start by perusing [this article](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html).

Comment: Thanks @DanGuzman. Will have a good read on the whole article. About the parameter sniffing, It's not a stored proc.

Comment: Although the article focuses on stored procedures, parameter sniffing apples to any parameterized query, not just stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try adding option(hash join) at the end of the query, if possible.  Once you start getting into large arity, loops join is not particularly efficient.  That would prove out if there is a more efficient plan (likely yes).

Without seeing more of the details (your screenshots are helpful but cut off whether auto-param or forced parameterization has kicked in and auto-parameterized your query), it is hard to confirm/deny this explicitly.  You can read more about parameter sniffing in a blog post I wrote a bit longer ago than I care to admit ;) :
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/queryoptteam/2006/03/31/i-smell-a-parameter/

Ultimately, if you update stats, dbcc freeproccache, or otherwise cause this plan to recompile, your odds of getting a faster plan in the cache are higher if you have this particular query + parameter values being executed often enough to sniff that during plan compilation.  Your other option is to add optimize for unknown hints which will disable sniffing and direct the optimizer to use an average value for the frequency of any filters over parameter values.  This will likely encourage more hash or merge joins instead of loops joins since the cardinality estimates of the operators in the tree will likely increase.